# What do these X's mean i'm trying to learn counting stars on Guitar but have no idea how to play these

Tags: guitar, tablature, mute

[image]

What do these X's mean i'm trying to learn counting stars on Guitar but have no idea how to play these. I would mute them but there is nothing to mute!

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/%D1%85-on-tablature-how-do-i-play-it